# EMM dashboard is blank

Tags: wso2

I've gotten WSO2 installed and it works. But after I login to EMM I get a blank page. Viewing the source is confirming that nothing is being returned.

I login, click "Go to url" for the dashboard, click "Mobile Management Console" and after I login I get redirected to a blank page.

Why am I not able to see the emm console?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use my public DNS instead of public IP with Amazon AWS. After changing HostName and MgtHostName in carbon.xml to my public dns, everything worked like a charm.